# Cocos2d X .Spontaneous unload of resources

Tags: memory, resources, textures, cocos2d-x, preload

On loading scene I preload all resources like sprites, sounds, etc. But one of my test devices (HTC Desire, Android 2.2.2) unloads resources after loading, so when the game tries to play some sound or draw sprite, it freezes for a moment to load the resource again.
This problem appers only on HTC Desire, I didn't met this problem on my other devices (Samsung Galaxy Ace, Android 2.3.6 & Acer A100 tab, Android 4.0.3).

Can someone tell me why this happens? Thanks.

This is how I preload resources:

```
for (.....)
{
            CCString* file = CCString::create(path.c_str());
            if(file) {
                CCTexture2D* texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage(file->getCString());
            }
}
```

I've also tried like this, but it gives the save result:

```
for (.....)
{
            CCString* file = CCString::create(path.c_str());
            if(file) {
                CCSpriteFrame* frame = new CCSpriteFrame();
                CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFrame(frame, file->getCString());
                frame->retain();
            }
}
```

In both ways CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->dumpCachedTextureInfo() says that all textures are loaded:

01-29 15:18:36.111: D/cocos2d-x debug info(7579): cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 53 textures, for 103840 KB (101.41 MB)

I also tried to reduce amount of preloaded textures to 31 (42.76 MB), but nothing changed.

P.S.: I repeat, this problem appers only on Desire with 2.2 Android OS ...

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for this behavior is [described here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/), under "avoid purging caches during memory warnings".

By default cocos2d (and I suppose cocos2d-x is no different) will purge all caches when a memory warning is received. This means you can preload assets as much as you want, there need only be one memory warning and all of the preloaded (and currently unused) textures will be unloaded.